# For what values of $a\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ do $(2,1)$ and $(2+i,a)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{Z}[i]^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> For what values of $a\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ do $(2,1)$ and $(2+i,a)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{Z}[i]^2$?

My original thought is to let $a=1+i$. But $(2,1)$ and $(2+i,1+i)$ don't span $\mathbb{Z}[i]^2$.

Comment: Are we considering $\mathbb{Z}[i]^2$ as a module over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, or over some other ring?

Comment: We consider $\mathbb{Z}[i]^2$ over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as I think there will be no solution if it's over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements $(2,1),(2+i,a) \in \mathbb{Z}[i]^2$ form a basis if and only if the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2+i \\ 1 & a \end{pmatrix}$$
has unit determinant in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, in other words, if and only if
$$2a-(2+i) \in \{ 1,i,{-1},{-i} \}$$
Thus the possible values of $a$
are
$$\frac{3+i}{2}, \quad 1+i, \quad \frac{1+2i}{2}, \quad 1$$
Of course, not all of these are elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$...

Comment: Did you mean $1+i$ where you wrote $1+2i$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I did indeed, thanks. [Since this was two years ago, I won't edit the answer since that will bump it to the front page.]

Answer (score 2):

I beg your pardon, but $(1,1)$ and $(2+i,1+i)$ **are** a basis of $\mathbf Z[i]^2$. The condition for $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ to be a basis of $R^2$ ($R$ a commutative ring) is the determinant of these vectors is a unit in $R$. The units in $\mathbf Z[i]$ are $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$.

For your initial question, the condition is
$$2a-2-i\in\{1,-1,i,-i\},\enspace\text{i.e.}\quad a\in\Bigl\{1,1+i,\frac{1+i}2,\frac{3+i}2\Bigr\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you look at $\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2+i\\ a\end{pmatrix}$ as a basis spanning $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, then for them to be a basis for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, of course $a$ must be in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, but the determinant of their matrix must be a unit.  The determinant is

$\det\begin{pmatrix}2&2+i\\1&a\end{pmatrix}=2a-(2+i)$.  We need this to be a unit, so either $1, i, -1$ or $-i$.  It cannot be $\pm 1$, so it must be $\pm i$.  Then this gives $a=1+i$ or $1$.  Why did you not believe that $a=1+i$ did not work?

Comment: I just can't prove that $(2+i,1+i)$ and $(2,1)$ span $\mathbb{Z}[i]^2$